# Replace double character with single in string

Tags: string, replaceall, substring

I have to replace double semicolon (;;) in a string with single comma(,) in an apex class. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the replaceAll() method from the [String class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm).

```
String testString = 'Hello;; my name is SF support.';
testString = testString.replaceAll(';;', ',');

System.debug(testString);
```

> Result: Hello, my name is SF support.